# Get song duration of songs in raw folder and convert it to String array?

Tags: android, audio, duration

Is it possible to get the duration of sounds in raw folder, and convert it to string array?
Something like this:

sound1 duration: 00:10sec

sound2 duration: 02:31sec

..

sound1235 duration: 00:31sec

and convert that into

```
String[] soundDuration = { "00:10","02:31"...."00:31"};
```

Comment: Yes, this is possible.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
    Uri mediaPath = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.your_song);
    MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    mmr.setDataSource(this, mediaPath);
```

then, access/save the info with

```
    String song_duration =mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
```

note that however this returns the duration in milliseconds, so i believe that you can do the following:

```
    Integer.parseInt(song_duration);
    song_duration = song_duration / 1000;
    String song_dur_str = "song_duration/60" +":" +"song_duration%60" + "sec"
```

Comment: No actually this doesn't work. And, perhaps I am wrong but this is only  for 1 song, not all files in raw folder. 
Ps. Sorry for late response, I thought I had already answered to your post.

Answer (score 0):

I havent tested this code ... Hope this will give you idea

```
     private String[][] getAllRawResources() {
          String[][] ids = null ;
          R.raw r = new R.raw() ;

          Field fields[] = R.raw.class.getDeclaredFields() ;
          ids = new String[fields.length][3] ;

          try {
        for( int i=0; i<fields.length; i++ ) {
          Field f = fields[i] ;
          ids[i][0] = f.getInt(r) ;
          ids[i][1] = f.getName();
          Log.i(TAG, "R.raw."+f.getName()+" = 0x"+Integer.toHexString(ids[i])) ;

    Uri mediaPath = Uri.parse(f.getPath());
        MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        mmr.setDataSource(this, mediaPath);
        String song_duration =mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);

Integer.parseInt(song_duration);
    song_duration = song_duration / 1000;
    String song_dur_str = "song_duration/60" +":" +"song_duration%60"
        id[i][2] = song_duration;

            }
          } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
          }

          return ids ;
        }
```

Comment: It did gave me an idea but it didn't work. The code you wrote had a few errors which I did not know how to solve.